# Linux: Extract values with one instance of record in file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I only want to extract those records which are occurring only once in the input file

> Input file 1

```
    CHEMBL184618
    CHEMBL184618
    CHEMBL198362
    CHEMBL198362
    CHEMBL218394
    CHEMBL218394
    CHEMBL221959
    CHEMBL221959
    CHEMBL24828 
    CHEMBL24827
```

> Expected Output

```
    CHEMBL24828
    CHEMBL24827
```

I have done sort Filename.txt | uniq -d to find the duplicated ids and save them in separate file. Then I find sort Filename.txt | uniq -c. Third step is to delete the duplicated ids from unique Ids. I want an efficient method.

Comment: Using `uniq` without the `-c` option does this.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen uniq considers the duplicates. I do not want to include them at all.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen `-c` option counts, `-u` will print the desired lines.

Comment: oh whoops, misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with:

```
uniq -u input_file
```

From `uniq` manual:

> -u, --unique
>
> only print unique lines

Answer (score 2):

Let say you have a file testFile.txt with the following inside:

```
CHEMBL184618
CHEMBL184618
CHEMBL198362
CHEMBL198362
CHEMBL218394
CHEMBL218394
CHEMBL221959
CHEMBL221959
CHEMBL24828 
CHEMBL24827
```

uniq will output all lines exactly once:

```
cat testFile.txt | uniq

CHEMBL184618
CHEMBL198362
CHEMBL218394
CHEMBL221959
CHEMBL24828 
CHEMBL24827
```

uniq -d will output all lines that appear more than once:

```
cat testFile.txt | uniq -d 

CHEMBL184618
CHEMBL198362
CHEMBL218394
CHEMBL221959
```

uniq -u will output all lines that appear exactly once:

```
cat testFile.txt | uniq -u

CHEMBL24828 
CHEMBL24827
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more in awk:

```
 awk '{a[$0] += 1}END{ for ( i in a ) if (a[i] == 1) print i }' file
```

Output:

```
CHEMBL24828 
CHEMBL24827
```

I assume that removing the leading spaces is not a problem.You could do that with something like:

```
sed -i 's/^ *//g'
```

Or the awk approach that Inian posted.